# IMP in oracle 12c does not create tables with IDENTITY feature

Tags: oracle, import, oracle12c

I exported an schema which has approximately 150 tables  using EXP.

Almost all of the tables in the schema have an IDENTITY column.

When I imported the .dmp file using IMP on different server it created all the table and imported the data but IDENTITY is removed.

Any suggestion?

Comment: EXPDB requires DB/PDB should be in ARCHIVELOG ON mode. But as it's development server I don't want to enable ARCHIVEL LOG.

Comment: I wonder, are the underlying sequences and defaults created or are they omitted?

Comment: IMP and EXP were deprecated in 11g. If you continue to use them you're going to have to live with the consequences.

Comment: @DavidFaber These are not sequence, there's new feature introduces in oracle 12C is IDENTITY (it's auto incrementer for the column). When I import the .dmp I don't see it on the column neither any sequences and defaults related to it.

Comment: "EXPDB requires DB/PDB should be in ARCHIVELOG ON mode" - where did you find that restriction? Can you provide a documentation reference?

Comment: @RajeshRanjan, I know what `IDENTITY` is and I also know that it works through the use of sequences. You can read more about it here: https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/identity-columns-in-oracle-12cr1#identity-columns

Comment: @AlexPoole You are right, I faced it while I was backing up the database. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

> Any suggestion?

Yes. Use Datapump instead.

Oracle implements Identity columns though system-generated sequences. This poses a problem for importing an identity column into a new database, because there is the possibility that the generated sequence name from the exported identity column will clash with an existing generated sequence. Datapump handles this by dropping the imported sequence and creating a fresh sequence which it associates with the identity column.

This capability is only available through Datapump. The old command line IMP and EXP utilities are no longer supported since 11g - [check the Utilities Guide's table of contents](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/toc.htm). The executables are only provided to handle old dumps - Datapump can't read Old Skool EXP files so we still have to use IMP to import them. But any new exports should be done using Datapump - especially if you want to take advantage of newer database features.